# In Pine Script, trying to print variable value from calculation to alert() function

Tags: pine-script

I have the following line on pine script:

```
differencevalue = math.abs(val-val_1)
plot(differencevalue, title="dvalue")
```

It successfully plots on indicator window.

I also have an alert function:

```
alert("{{dvalue}} LONG -> "+ sym, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

But I can not get this alert function to print the value of "differencevalue".

The rest of the alert works but "differencevalue" prints..

```
{{dvalue}}
```

I would appreciate some feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alert() functions are not subject to placeholders only, and you can use any variable in them.

This is from TradingView blog [post](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/our-new-alerts-allow-for-dynamic-messages-22588/):

> Also it’s worth remembering that there’s no limit on the number of variables that can be used in the dynamic alert message and that placeholders are no longer necessary, as any variable used in a script can also be used in the new `alert()` function calls, as long as it is in string format.

You can try this:

```
differencevalue = math.abs(val-val_1)
plot(differencevalue, title="dvalue")
alert(str.tostring(differencevalue) + "LONG ->" + sym)
```